# Do any compatible triangles make a tetrahedron?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

When picking side lengths for a triangle, not every set of three positive reals $\ell_1=AB, \ell_2=AC, \ell_3=BC$ defines a triangle; the lengths must satisfy certain other inequalities.

Consider four triangles with side lengths $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3)$, $(\ell_2,\ell_4,\ell_5)$, $(\ell_3,\ell_5,\ell_6)$, $(\ell_1,\ell_4,\ell_6)$ (*i.e.* the triples each satisfy the inequalities to make valid triangles, and the relevant side lengths are shared between the triangles to form a tetrahedron's net).

Does it follow that there is a tetrahedron $ABCD$ with edge lengths $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3,\ell_4,\ell_5,\ell_6$ or are there additional constraints? If it does (as I suspect), is there a straightforward way to explain why there can never be any problem 'fitting the triangles together'?

Comment: A concrete counterexample would be $\ell_1=\ell_2=\ell_3=14$ and $\ell_4=\ell_5=\ell_6=8$.

Comment: Another is $l_1=l_2=l_3=l_4=l_5=4$ and $l_6=7$.

Comment: The extra condition needed for a viable (non-degenerate) tetrahedron is that the corresponding [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Menger_determinant#Definition) (with $n=3$) for the square of volume be positive. Note that the faces are viable when the $n=2$ determinants (equivalent to Heron's formula) are positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Draw triangle $l_1,l_2,l_3$ and put spheres with radii $l_4,l_5,l_6$ in the vertices. Hopefully, one can imagine how spheres can intersect pairwise but not have a common point.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. Would it violate this SE's policies if I amended the question to ask about the condition in terms of edge lengths for the tetrahedron to exist?

Comment: I can add the answer to this question in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, as follows, thinking as I go.

Pick $2$ triangles arbitrarily: without loss of generality $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABD$. They fit together along side $AB$. Imagine the line of intersection being a hinge.

If you close them together, unless the triangles are congruent, there will be an angle $\angle CBD$ which is non-zero.

Let $\triangle BCD$ be such that $\angle CBD$ is smaller than that formed by $\angle CBD$ between $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABD$.

Then the triangles cannot be linked up to form a tetrahedron.